# Find the expressions for the common difference and common ratio

Tags: sequences-and-series

> The first 2 terms of a geometric progression (first term $a$ and common ratio $r$) are the same as the first 2 terms of an arithmetic progression (first term $a$ and common difference $d$). The third term of the geometric progression is twice as big as the third term of the arithmetic progression. Find 2 different expressions for $d$ and hence or otherwise find the 2 possible values of $r$.

So I've tried to tackle this problem, to no avail:

$$ ar = a + d$$

$$ar^2 = 2(a + 2d)$$

So using this I found $d = ar -a $ and $d = \dfrac{1}{4}ar^2 - \dfrac{1}{2}a$, so $$ ar -a =\dfrac{1}{4}ar^2 - \dfrac{1}{2}a$$

$$a(r^2-4r+2)=0$$

Here I knew I was wrong, because I'm sure that you're not supposed to be using the quadratic for this exercise (judging from how much time you have).

So where did I go wrong?

Comment: Nowhere.  It just takes a few seconds to solve the quadratic.  And a few seconds more to get the corresponding $d=a(r-1)$. Remarkable: $r$ doesn't depend on $a$, whereas $d$ does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that you've done nothing wrong. (*There's* an odd thing to say.)

It's worth noting that if $a=0,$ then we get $d=0$ immediately, but $r$ can take literally *any* value. Since the problem expects two possible values for $r,$ then we clearly must assume $a\neq0.$

Since $a\ne 0,$ then $r^2-4r+2=0,$ and from there, the quadratic formula will give you the two possible values for $r$. Alternately, you could note the following: $$r^2-4r+2=0\\r(r-4)+2=0\\(r-2+2)(r-2-2)+2=0\\(r-2)^2-2^2+2=0\\(r-2)^2-2=0$$

This is an end-around method of completing the square by using the difference of squares formula, from which you can readily conclude that $r=2\pm\sqrt2,$ if you'd rather avoid the quadratic formula.